# Runtime 13 Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I get run time error 13 when executing following code

```
Dim sh, shmem As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Set shmem = Sheets("SHEET1")
Set sh = Sheets("SHEET2")
For Each rw In sh.Rows
    If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" And sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Dim bdaytest As Variant
        Dim match1 As Double

        bdaytest = .Index((shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)) * (shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)), 0)
        'match1 = .Match(1, .Index((shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)) * (shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)), 0), 0)
        bdaytest = .Index(1, shmem.Range("D2:D121"), match1)
    End With
Next rw
```

The Error Happens in following line which I extracted from the 2 line (commented out now)

```
bdaytest = .Index((shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)) * (shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)), 0)
'match1 = .Match(1, .Index((shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)) * (shmem.Range("A2:A121") = sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)), 0), 0)
```

I understand that the error must happen because *bdaytest* is the wrong data type but I'm not sure and up to now I couldn't find any solution. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: I want to find out the Row Number of the Line where 2 Columns (A & B) have a requested Value. The requested Value is found in `sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1)` and `sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2)`

Comment: can you describe what is the problem you trying to solve ?

Comment: hope my edit helps @EricK.

Comment: you want all the Row number for record that match A & B ? or only 1 Row number that matched ?

Comment: @EricK. A&B together are like the Primary Key therefore there can only be one result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create arrays using `=` and `*` like that in VBA, unlike in a formula. What you can do is use `Application.Countifs` like this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim shmem             As Worksheet
Dim rw                    As Range

Set shmem = Sheets("SHEET1")
Set sh = Sheets("SHEET2")

For Each rw In sh.Rows
    If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" And sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

    With Application
        Dim bdaytest      As Variant
        Dim match1        As Double

        bdaytest = .Match(1, .CountIfs(sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1), shmem.Range("A2:A121"), _
                                        sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2), shmem.Range("B2:B121")), 0)
        If Not IsError(bdaytest) Then bdaytest = shmem.Range("D2:D121").Cells(bdaytest)
    End With
Next rw
```

Note: `WorksheetFunction.Countifs` will not work.

Comment: Thanks @Rory ! I hade tried variations of WorksheetFunction.Countifs earlier. Unseccesfullyy of course but with Application it works perfect!